# play framework - error parsing expression in build.sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am getting this strange parsing exception while trying to build my play project.
It complains about the semi-colon that is no where in the file.
Below is the error message and an extract from the `build.sbt` (line 12 & 13) file.

```
.../zentasks/build.sbt:12: error: eof expected but ';' found.
libraryDependencies += javaEbean
^
[error] Error parsing expression.  Ensure that settings are separated by blank lines.
```

**Build.sbt** file:

```
...
libraryDependencies += javaJdbc
libraryDependencies += javaEbean
...
```

**Note**:

I have got the solution but thought of putting up this question/solution for a while so that other newbies like me don't waste any time figuring this problem.

**SOLUTION**:
I dont understand why play throws this confusing error message. I don't see where that semi-colon is. However the solution is to separate the dependencies by blank line as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += javaJdbc

libraryDependencies += javaEbean
```

Also refer: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html#how-build-sbt-defines-settings

Note: feel free to add to the solution or correct it.

Comment: Thanks gourlaysama! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, the semicolon stuff is a bit misleading. On the other hand it also told you: Ensure that settings are separated by blank lines. :)

If you prefer a more compact way you could also write:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     javaJdbc,
     javaEbean 
)
```